# Can't delete data on sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to delete a single player in my database with a button.

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

                db.addContact(new PlayerData(name,score));
                Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting .."); 

            } 
      });



          load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    thedb = (ArrayList<PlayerData>) db.getAllContacts();
                    String showName = db.getContact(8).getName();
                    int showScore = db.getContact(8).getscore();
                    saved.setText("Player Name: "+showName+" Player Score: "+showScore);

                } 
          });


          delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    db.deleteContact();


                } 
          });
```

However in delete button an error displays on db.deletecontact();

I can't figure out how to delete it since a friend of mine just gave me the code of the Database Manager.

Here is the snippet from the  DatabaseManager.

```
    public void deleteContact(PlayerData contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}
```

db.deleteContact(); needs an argument or parameters but i don't know what to put. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be returning a PlayerData object. You get one of these in the load clickListener.

```
db.deleteContact(db.getContact(<entry number of player>));
```

This should provide you with the PlayerData object to pass as the parameter for the deleteContact method.

Hope this helps

Comment: Finally I got it working. However when I load the contact from index 1 and display it in a textview, and i decide to delete it with the delete button, the application force stops.why is this happening?

Comment: Would need the error to work it out. Is it an SQLException? You need to make sure that the PlayerData object exists.

Comment: Need help! Suddenly, when I click the load button it force stops and says :

08-30 18:21:33.465: E/AndroidRuntime(597): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
08-30 18:21:33.465: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at com.example.simplegame.TotalResults$2.onClick(TotalResults.java:53)


but the logcat display says it is inserting. Please help!

Comment: That means you are trying to read something from the a cursor which is empty. You need to make sure that you are checking cursors for size before reading.

Comment: how can i know if the cursor is empty. the logcat says i'm inserting the information on the database.

Comment: cursor.getCount();
Logcat says you are inserting, which means you are doing something after inserting the value to cause it to crash. Look at line 53 for TotalResults for a starter.

Comment: here is the snippet in line 53:


String showName = db.getContact(0).getName();

Comment: so there is no contact in element 0. You need to stop hardcoding id's. Use the (ArrayList<PlayerData>) db.getAllContacts(); to get values from the DB to ensure they exist.

Comment: Without the full code I can't help. Raise another question and link it in here.

Comment: here is the link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531513/cant-get-data-from-database

Answer (score 0):

As in load button click you are passing index of contact like

```
db.getContact(8).getscore();
```

Same as this I think you should pass in this also like

```
db.deleteContact(7); //index of 7th contact
```